# Dcount,Dmin,DMax,DAvg very slow to update on opening form

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form in Access with 6 text boxes. In these boxes I use expressions with DCount, DMax, DMin, DAvg. However it gets updates very slowly. How can I improve the pace? Is there an alternative for the Expressions

```
DCount("*";"FieldA")
```

in VBA or in any other SQLcode?

Comment: Curious how those even worked. [Domain functions](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dcount.php) run with comma separated args: `Dfunc(fieldname, tablename, [optional criteria])`. And like SQL's `Count(*)` aggregate, only DCount can use asterisk.

Comment: I had them false for the DMax, DMin and DAvg functions. Although ; is used for German operating system as a separator. So apart from DCount which is the faster method?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could look at making it a bound form?

If it already is a bound form then perhaps you could add those fields to the query the form is based upon. If its a bound form based upon a table then you could make a query instead with those extra fields.

Comment: What if the Form in Unbound and has many Queries to be Bound on? How can I select multiple queries?

Answer (score 1):

If you pull from the same table (from "FieldA"), you create a query that pulls these values in one go:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("YourQuery").OpenRecordset()

Me!AverageTextbox.Value = rs!AverageField.Value
Me!CountTextbox.Value = rs!CountField.Value
' etc.
```

Comment: In the BuildEvent of the Textbox. I have used your following code  Private Sub Dunkel_Click()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Tables").OpenRecordset()
Me!CountTextbox.Value = rs!CountField.Value
End Sub.  But it does not return me anything in the textbox when I go to form view. Where am I going wrong?